# Stuck trying to find a way to evaluate this taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am currently trying to evaluate the following:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^t \left(n-1\right) \dfrac{p^n}{n!}$$

I'm not sure if this is a Taylor series type of equation but it sure looks like one and thus hoping to solve this with Taylor series.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from? It could give us a hint as to how we could solve the problem

Comment: also, please add some context, show your progress or where you're stuck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pull it apart:
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)\frac{p^n}{n!} &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n\frac{p^n}{n!} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p^n}{n!} \\
&= \left(p\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right) - \left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{p^n}{n!}-1\right)\\
&= p e^p-e^p+1 \\
&= (p-1)e^p+1
\end{align}
Here we have used the fact that $e^p = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{p^n}{n!} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$.